# GWT Yui Spotlight Carousel issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, yui

We are trying to use `yui carousel` in our **gwt** application. But in gwt sample (spotlight sample) 5 images are showing. But we need only three images if we give three images same functionality is not happening like:

[gwt-yui-carousel-googlecode-svn-gwtyuicarousel.spotlight.SpotLight](http://gwt-yui-carousel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/com.gwtyuicarousel.spotlight.SpotLight/spotlight.html)

1.We are not able to click on first and second images?
2.Last and last but one images are not visible?

Can we modify the above mentioned sample to work for three images instead of five? If yes,please let us know.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently worked on a `Carousel` for **GWT**, but i used `iScroll` Implementation.

Please check the links,

[apollo-rvs-appspot_carouselPoc](http://apollo-rvs.appspot.com/#carouselPoc)

[cubiq_iscroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

This carousel can be customized for any number of images. I needed 3 Images on a Single View, so i adjusted in a similar way.